# How to search for a particular page?

Tags: support, search

Lets say there are 98,765 pages of questions in Stack Overflow and I want to see what is on page 689. How do I do that? One way is to manually lick your way to the page, which sounds very rudimentary to me. Anyone know a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the URL of your search you can specify a particular page to land at.

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=mySearchTerm
```

By changing `page=2` to `page=689` you can jump straight over to that particular page.